# POSIX locale when I use SSH with a command line

Tags: linux, ssh, localization

When I SSH into an Arch Linux server and include a command line, I end up with a POSIX locale:

```
laptop.lan$ ssh server.lan locale
LANG=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=
laptop.lan$
```

As far as I can tell, locale is set up correctly on the server. `/etc/locale.conf` looks like this:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

And, when I SSH in normally, my locale is fine:

```
laptop.lan$ ssh server.lan
server.lan$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
server.lan$
```

What’s going on here, and how can I make one-shot commands use my preferred locale, too?

Answer (score 2):

I guess some defaults are applied here, I am not sure about version but my first thoughts are below

## Forward locale

```
SendEnv LANG LC_*
```

Or

you can change the configuration of the server, by editing /etc/ssh/sshd_config on the remote machine:

## Accept locale

```
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
```

Or

## You can use ssh config file pass your locale to ~/.ssh/config and use

```
ssh -F ~/.ssh/config your_user@your_host
```

Or

## use below way for inline changes

```
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8" ssh usernae@yourserver
```

Comment: but why it works fine on ssh and not on ssh command? the same login scripts are executed.

Comment: AFAIK difference is interactive and non-interactive shell, when you pass command like ssh <host> <command> it will call non-interactive shell, non-interactive shell call `BASH_ENV` instead of other user profiles scripts.

Comment: This works for me.
‘ssh user@yourserver LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 command‘

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed, that the problem occurs when I have `fish` (the fish-shell) set as default (`chsh`). When I changed my shell back to bash, the locale works as expected.

So:

```
chsh /bin/bash
```

Comment: only shell on my system is bash, and the problem happens as describe on the question.